# iphone app programming: existing plist file for time zones?

Tags: iphone, timezone

Is there a plist file that lists the timezones and maybe a corresponding city? Being able to select a couple of time zones (independent of the users location/iphone settings) is a requirement in an application I am writing.

I am hoping I don't have to reformat some existing list into a plist.

Thanks,

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API that will pull all that time zone information for you. Check out the Tableview Suite sample code

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html